# How to identify the row ranges that contribute into a colour formatted cell which is a subtotal, and applying to across multiple columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really new in VBA codes and trying to improve to be better. Need help if anyone could assist me further in my codes. Thanks for your patience in advance.

What I'm trying to achieve is running a code through a table with multiple rows and columns, to copy a selected range into another worksheet of the same workbook. I'm trying to identify which cells has a color formatted (for eg.H2). Once identified, I want to go back 1st column of the same row (in this example, it will be A2). And from there, run the code going down the column to see repeated names (column A is names). Once detected a different name source, I want to copy the range of 1st name found (in this example, it will be A2), to the last name (for eg.A6) across multiple columns (Column A to newlastcol). A7 is found to be of a different name.

The column A data in table is already sorted from A to Z and the cells that are color formatted is the subtotal calculated for the same name and it is always displayed at the top. Its row number will always be the first name found in Column A.

```
    Dim StartTest As Range, StartName As Range
    Dim lastrow As Integer, lastcol As Integer
    Dim R As Integer, C As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

  'Filter off Coloured Cells
    Set StartTest = Cells(1, 1)
    StartTest.Select

   Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
       newlastrow = ActiveCell.Row
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

    StartTest.Select
   Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
       newlastcol = lastcol + 1
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   Loop

   NextColumn:
    C = StartTest(1).Column
    R = StartTest(1).Row

    Set filterrng = Range(Cells(R, C), Cells(newlastrow, C))

    Cells(1, C).Select
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True Then
    GoTo NextPart
        End If

    For j = 2 To newlastrow

        Cells(j, C).Select
            If Cells(j, C).Interior.Color = 255 Then
                Cells(j, 1).Select

                **'Problem Line**
                Set StartName = Cells(j, 1)
                NameC = StartName(1).Column
                NameR = StartName(j).Row

                StartName.Select
                For k = NameR To newlastrow
                If Cells(NameR, NameC) <> Cells(NameR + 1, NameC) Then
                    namelastrow = k
                    Range(Cells(NameR, NameC), Cells(namelastrow, newlastcol)).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                End If
                Set StartName = StartName.Offset(1, 0)
                Next k
             End If

           Next j
            Cells(R, C + 1).Select

            Set filterrng = filterrng.Offset(0, 1)
            Set StartTest = StartTest.Offset(0, 1)

            GoTo NextColumn

    End Sub
```

I am able to let the code run through multiple columns, and I am able to place back cursor back to the cell of same row of column (A2). But I have problems from the 'StartDate section', which is the part to check repeated names within a same column or multiple rows and highlighting the range to copy into another sheet.

Thank you for everyone's feedback in advance. Really appreciated it if there are other suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Do Until StrComp(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = True Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

```
            ActiveCell.Resize(1, 5).Copy

                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

                Sheets("C").Activate

                ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Sheets("AB").Activate



    Loop
```

End If

```
Range("g3").Select

    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then

        Range("a1:a30").Find(what:="yelow").Activate




    Do Until StrComp(ActiveCell.Value, "yelow") = True Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

            ActiveCell.Resize(1, 5).Copy

                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

                Sheets("C").Activate

                ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Sheets("AB").Activate


    Loop

    End If


Loop
```

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: finally like:For Each cel In Range("F2:g3")


    If cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
            
                    
 Do Until StrComp(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = True Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    
                ActiveCell.Resize(1, 5).Copy

then use the previous code.....